# Esoteric Programming Language

Tags: computer-puzzle

I need help deciphering this 'joke,' but I cannot figure out the primer/syntax. Does anyone recognize this?

> ++[------>+<]>.++[->++<]>+.-[-->+<]>.....---[-->+++<]>-.+[--->++<]>+...+[----->+<]>.++[-->+++<]>.[--->++<]>.+[--->++<]>+..+++.---.....+++.-...........+.---..+++.---...........+++.---....+++.-...........+.---......+++.-.+.

Only hint: While the joke itself is not entirely esoteric, the presentation in its abstract sense is, and turing-complete.

SOLVED! New hint: trying to understand it will seriously f*** with your brain ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is

> [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) code that prints `+[----->+++<]>++.+++++.-----------.++.+++++++++++.++++.-----------.++++++.-.`, which is itself Brainfuck code that prints "`inception`".

Comment: A mod used a swearword! Flagged! :-P